# Generating aes cbc key from password and iv in dart

Tags: c#, flutter, dart, encryption, aes

anyone havean idea how can i generate a key for aes encryption in dart from iv and password?
like this code written in C#:

```
 var spec = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PASSWORD), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SALT), 65536);
        byte[] key = spec.GetBytes(16);
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/cryptography/latest/cryptography/Pbkdf2-class.html

Comment: Any problem with the above code? What behaviour do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Martheen I've tried that method, but it only comes with Sha256 and Sha512 algorithm and what I need is sha1.

Comment: Can you clarify the version and platform? The doc said it should accept any MacAlgorithm and it includes Hmac.sha1(). Update your question with your failing code an the error message you receive

Comment: @Martheen I've tried that, and I took a look at the source code it has only sha256() and sha512()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, I generated the key using C# code then I used it as constant in my flutter app, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).